# Serving a html file using a script that imports a class from other .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express server serving a html(index.html) page that uses a script(app.js). this script needs to import a class from another .js file (TheClass.js). Current code:

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile('index.html', __dirname);
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening at port 3000');
})
----------------------------------------------------
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <style src="style.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
---------------------------------------------------
//app.js
import { TheClass } from './TheClass.js';
alert('Hello');
---------------------------------------------------
//TheClass.js
export class TheClass{}
```

With this code, the app.js script does not run. If i remove the: import { TheClass } from './TheClass.js'; line , the app.js script runs fine. I want to be able to import The class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use import/export modules like that in a web browser. You probably see an error in the JavaScript console in your browser.

There are a many different packages to shim browsers to support this kind of thing to some extent. But I think your best bet is to use some sort of JavaScript bundler to package your JS into one file that the browser will use.

Check out:
http://browserify.org/